# How to create a table with data from other tables in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

How to create a table that with data from 6 other tables that have the same columns? The table names are: ab1_2, ab3, ab4, ab5 and ab6.

This is a spatial data with the Postgis extension enabled so they have geometry that I need to put in the first and second columns. The output table that I'm looking for is something like:

X coordinate | Y coordinate | field 3 | field 8 | field 20

Comment: Have you already tried using UNION (or UNION ALL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the PostgreSQL documentation:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM ab1_2;
```

Replace the `*` with the field names (with alias if you need to change the name) you need. You can put in the other 5 tables as `UNION`:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS
SELECT * FROM ab1_2
UNION
SELECT * FROM ab3
UNION
SELECT * FROM ab4
UNION
SELECT * FROM ab5
UNION
SELECT * FROM ab6;
```

In the second one only the field names are needed. No use to give them an alias.

Or write 5 SQLs in the form:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT * FROM other_table;
```

Comment: How can I include more than just "old_table"? I have 6 tables that I need to include

Comment: Changed my answer. I kept my answer very generic to give you an idea on how to do it.

Comment: I got an error http://i.imgur.com/kfvAhvB.jpg

Comment: inserting into got me a lack of space error. guess I need to talk to the database guy for that but insert worked and union didnt

Comment: Checked the error that you got. I guess that the table `ab6` has a different order of the fields or one of the field has a different type. Check the table definitions. If you had not run into space problems then you would have seen that the insert of `ab6` would have failed too.

Comment: You're right. It returned the following error ERROR:  Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (27700)
********** Error **********

ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (27700)
SQL state: 22023 

How can I fix it?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I've managed to fix it with simply using SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('ab6','geom',27700);